# Laravel 5.4 from 5.3 : Error getOtherKey()

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I was getting the relationship as in laravel 5.3 and was working fine:

```
//execute the relation of the given model
$data = $model->{$info["relation"]}();

// get the type of the relation
$class = get_class($data);
$dataType = explode("\\", $class);
$relationType = end($dataType);

$options["columns"][$key]["relationType"] = $relationType;

// if its a simple belongs-to statement
if($relationType == "BelongsTo") {

    // get all belongs-to query info
    $otherTable = $data->getRelated()->getTable();
    $foreignKey = $data->getQualifiedForeignKey();
    $otherKey = $data->getOtherKey();

    // manually join using it
    $retrievedRecords->leftJoin($otherTable . ' as ' . $info["relation"], $info["relation"] . '.' . $otherKey, '=', $foreignKey);

} else if($relationType == "HasMany" || $relationType == "HasOne") {

    // get all has-many query info
    $otherTable = $data->getRelated()->getTable();
    $foreignKey = $data->getPlainForeignKey();
    $parentKey = $data->getQualifiedParentKeyName();

    // manually join using it
    $retrievedRecords->leftJoin($otherTable . ' as ' . $info["relation"], $info["relation"] . '.' . $foreignKey, '=', $parentKey);

}
```

Now i downloaded fresh `laravel 5.4` and it gives me error :

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getOtherKey()`

As the `getOtherKey()` exists in the above code in `if()` section.

**Is there any alternative for that ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getOtherKey` method has been renamed to `getOwnerKey`. So you can get the owner key by saying:

```
$ownerKey = $data->getOwnerKey();
```